# CSS fade with JS callback to set css display on completion interrupts animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition, banner

Edit: JSFiddle as per request: https://jsfiddle.net/5anz0kgt/1/

Edit 2: It seems the animation interruption in fact is related to the order of the elements... If the new banenr layer is on top of the old one, the animation will be smooth. If the new banner is beneath, the animation appears choppy. 
The new question therefore becomes why, and how can I fix this?

I am currently finishing up a small banner, and am having some trouble with animations.

Originally, I just had the following functions controlling the banner visibility and animations (which worked):

```
function fadeOut(el){
    el.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    el.style.opacity = 0;
}

function fadeIn(el){
    el.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    el.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

But I quickly noticed that this (of course) made buttons unclickable on the banners due to element stacking.

I therefore decided to set display: none on non visible banner layers. For fading in, I simply added

```
el.style.display = "";
```

but for fading out I needed to insure the css animation had completed before I could hide the layer. So I added (courtesy of http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback):

```
var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent(el);
    transitionEvent && el.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function() {
        el.style.display = "none";
    });
```

to the end of the fadeOut() function. The issue now is that the transition is now very abrupt (most of the time - it seems to work a small subset of the time).

Leaving only the display code in fadeIn() works, pointing to the fadeOut() changes as the issue. Watching in firebug, I can see the display changes coming into play only after the opacity animation finishes, however.

How can I insure that my display code doesn't interrupt the animation, or alternatively, how else can I solve the element stacking problem?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle so we can muck around with your HTML/JS?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5anz0kgt/1/
There you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've had a good look at your code. I've created a fix for the transition issue by setting z-index in the fadeOut/fadeIn functions to ensure that the correct element is visible on top regardless of stacking.

Furthermore, there is another bug. The animation loop continues regardless of user input so the user interaction and automatic looping fight against each other, to get around this you can use clearInterval to stop a setInterval function (specifically the animation loop in this case).

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating both of the above https://jsfiddle.net/Lmtpw6yq/3/
Note that i've add another function select_banner which is called onClick instead of activate_banner so that the animation loop can be interrupted:

```
// stores ID of current animation loop setInterval so can interrupt
var animationTick;

function select_banner(banner_id) {
   if (animationTick) {
       // stop animation loop
       window.clearInterval(animationTick);
    }
    activate_banner(banner_id);
    animation_loop();
}
```

animationTick is set to the ID of the current setInterval tick in the animation loop function by calling setInterval like so:

```
function animation_loop() {
    animationTick = setInterval(function(){
        ... 
    }, 3000);
}
```

One final note is the while loops. They work but are terribly inefficient, firstly you are using getElementById repeatedly to find the same elements causing your js to traverse the dom over and over again unnecessarily. Also your condition for breaking the while loops (i.e. searching for an ID that doesn't exist) causes the js to check the ID of literally every node in the document which is less than ideal.

Since the number of banners doesn't change it would be better to find all the banners once and store references to them in an array at the beginning then use for loops to loop over the array instead of the while loops.

Comment: Added a JSFiddle to the op